# What can I expect regarding performance if I upgrade from Windows 7 to 8?

Tags: windows-8-upgrade

What can I expect regarding performance if I upgrade from Windows 7 to 8?

Especially, are there any risks of a poorer performance?
(With little RAM for example)

This is for a Netbook with 1G RAM.

What about Windows 8.1?

Comment: I would not upgrade to Windows 8 if you only have 1GB of memory. Sounds like you are moving from hardware sold that came with `Windows 7 Starter` or some other reduced functionality version.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference at the system requirements. So you **could** update without to have to worry, that the speed will be worse.

> Processor: 1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster with support for PAE, NX, and SSE2
>
> RAM: 1 gigabyte (GB) (32-bit) or 2 GB (64-bit)
>
> Hard disk space: 16 GB (32-bit) or 20 GB (64-bit)
>
> Graphics card: Microsoft DirectX 9 graphics device with WDDM driver

But Windows 7 has for example the starter-edition which fits well at netbooks. This version doesn't exist for windows 8.

Also windows 8 apps need a resolution of `1366x768` to work well. So your netbook has to have this resolution.

But beside that, windows 8 works quite good on less powerful PCs.

So you probably can expect an equally well performance or even better than windows 7 if you haven't used the windows 7 starter-edition before.

Comment: I was updating the answer. But thx anyway.

Comment: You should try and post complete answers the first time.

Comment: I accidently posted the answer before I have finished my answer.